# How to call dynamically an method in PHP?

Tags: php

Example: I have an variable like

```
$method = "doSomething";
```

Assume that I have an $myObject which knows a nonstatic, public method doSomething()

Could I then just call that method by doing this?

```
$myObject->$method();
```

Or is there another / better way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can do that :

```
$myObject->$method();
```

This is called [Variable functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php)

And here is the code that proves it :

```
class ClassA {
    public function method() {
        echo 'glop';
    }
}

$a = new ClassA();
$methodName = 'method';
$a->$methodName();
```

Gets you this output :

```
glop
```

Which means the method has been called ;-)

Another way would be to use [`call_user_func`](http://php.net/call_user_func) or [`call_user_func_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) :

```
call_user_func(array($a, $methodName));
```

Here, you don't need this -- but you'd have to use that if your method was `static`, at least for PHP <= 5.2

Comment: Maybe add the link to `Variable Functions` in the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php

Comment: @Gordon : Thanks for the suggestion ! I've edited my answer to add that link, and the term "Variable functions" :-)

Comment: My goal is to be the one who asked the most questions on SO ;-) lol

Answer (score 4):

Yes, however it is recommended that you first ensure the method exists prior to calling it:

```
if (method_exists(array($myObject, $method)) {
    $myObject->$method();
}
```